# How to check last character in command line arguements?

Tags: c, command-line

So im trying to count the number of files in the command line, heres what ive got so far

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
int cCount = 0;
int cHeadCount = 0;
int objCount = 0; 
int makeCount = 0;
int othCount =0;

for(int i = 1; i< argc; i++){
    /*
    if argv[i] last char is c 
        cCount++;

    if argv[i] last char is h 
        cHeadCount++;

    and so on for the rest

    */
printf("C Source: %d\n", cCount);
printf("C Header: %d\n", cHeadCount);
printf("Object: %d\n", objCount);
printf("Make: %d\n", makeCount);
printf("Other: %d\n", othCount);
}
```

so if you type in something like `$ ./fm main.c main.o sub.c sub.o` you should get

```
C source: 2
C header: 0
Object: 2
Make: 0
Other: 0
```

What i need help is the `if` statements inside the for loop. BTW is the for loop correct? Is there a function that will return the last character of a string? From what Ive seen, I dont seem to recall one but I could be very wrong.

If im going about this wrong, or on right track, please tell me. Any help appreciated.

EDIT:

Heres what I have inside the `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++){
    int len = strlen (argv[i]);

    if ((argv[i][len - 2] != '.') ){
        if((strcmp(argv[i], "Makefile")==0) || (strcmp(argv[i], "makefile")==0)){
        makeCount++;
    }else{
        othCount++;
        continue; //if i take this out, it counts `other` objects wrong too
    }
    }

    if(argv[i][len - 1] == 'c'){
        cCount++;

    }

    else if(argv[i][len - 1] == 'h'){
        cHeadCount++;

    }

    else if(argv[i][len - 1] == 'o'){
        objCount++;

    }

    else {
        othCount++;           
    }       

}
```

So the problem now is that its not recognizing `makefile`s as a Makefile. It counting them as `Other`. So where I should have say 5 `Makefile`s and 10 `Other` files, its saying i have 0 `makefiles` and 15 `Other` files.  `c`, `h` and `o` files work/count fine. Any help appreciated

Comment: like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kUoEo8AKZWhGMdJe)

Comment: Or you can use `strrchr` to get a pointer to the last `c, h, or o` and check `!*(p+1)` to confirm it is the last character in the argument.

Comment: If you execute like `$ ./fm Makefile` in the current code(Add `#include <string.h>`), you get `Make: 1 Other: 1`. It does not become `Make: 0`. Also, it is not good to use `len-2` or `len-1` without guard.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY so it _should_ be working?

Comment: like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sPxCjLKifgUgEkrD)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY ok, I think I _may_ know what wrong. In my tests, some are written as `directory/Makefile` or `directory/test.c`. so for the ones with the file extension, it works, but it doesnt recognize `directory/Makefile` because it sees it as a whole string. so how would i make it so it only reads from the last `/` character?

Comment: You can search for `/` by `strrchr` and use `strcmp` from the next position. like `char *slash = strrchar(argv[i], '/'); if(slash == NULL){...} else { if(strcmp(slash+1, "Makefile")==0) || ...) {....}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [strrchr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strrchr) like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int cCount, cHeadCount, objCount, makeCount, othCount;
    cCount = cHeadCount = objCount = makeCount = othCount = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++){
        char *filename = strrchr(argv[i], '/');
        filename = filename ? filename + 1 : argv[i];

        char *ext = strrchr(filename, '.');
        if(strcmp(filename, "Makefile") == 0 || strcmp(filename, "makefile") == 0){//or use strcasecmp ?
            ++makeCount;
        } else if(ext == NULL) {
            ++othCount;
        } else if(ext[1] == 'c' && ext[2] == 0){
            ++cCount;
        } else if(ext[1] == 'h' && ext[2] == 0){
            ++cHeadCount;
        } else if(ext[1] == 'o' && ext[2] == 0){//or strcmp(ext, ".o")==0
            ++objCount;
        } else {
            ++othCount;
        }
    }
    printf("C Source: %d\n", cCount);
    printf("C Header: %d\n", cHeadCount);
    printf("Object: %d\n", objCount);
    printf("Make: %d\n", makeCount);
    printf("Other: %d\n", othCount);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This works :) Can you explain me what the line `filename = filename ? filename + 1 : argv[i];` is doing?

Comment: @RobBor If there is no `/`, `argv[i]` is used as  file name, and in exist cases use from the next position.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strlen() to determine the length of each string in argv. Knowing the length you should be able to peak at the last element in the array.

NOTE: I won't write the code for your homework assignments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string function `strlen` which calculates the length of string and to use this you have to include header `<string.h>`. And from that you can check the last index of every word of command line argument that which condition it satisfies , like

```
for(int i = 1; i< argc; i++){
        int l=strlen(argv[i]);
    if(argv[i][l-1]=='c')
        cCount++;
    else if(argv[i][l-1]=='h')
        cHeadCount++;
    else if(argv[i][l-1]=='o')
        objCount++;
    else if(argv[i][l-1]=='m')
        makeCount++;
    else othCount++;


   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `switch` statement to do this:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
        int cCount = 0;
        int cHeadCount = 0;
        int objCount = 0;
        int makeCount = 0;
        int othCount =0;
        int len = 0;

        for(int i = 1; i< argc; i++){
                len = strlen (argv[i]);
                /* Assuming that any argv (filename) which either 
                 * do not have any extension or extension of 
                 * more than 1 character goes under "other" file catagory
                 */
                if (len > 2 && (argv[i][len - 2] != '.')){
                        othCount++;
                        continue;
                }
                switch(argv[i][len - 1]){
                        case 'h':
                                cHeadCount++;
                        break;
                        case 'c':
                                cCount++;
                        break;
                        case 'o':
                                objCount++;
                        break;
                        case 'm':
                                makeCount++;
                        break;
                        default:
                                othCount++;
                        break;
                }
        }
        printf("C Source: %d\n", cCount);
        printf("C Header: %d\n", cHeadCount);
        printf("Object: %d\n", objCount);
        printf("Make: %d\n", makeCount);
        printf("Other: %d\n", othCount);
        return 0;
}
```

The output of the program:

```
$ ./fm main.c main.o sub.c sub.o
C Source: 2
C Header: 0
Object: 2
Make: 0
Other: 0
```

Comment: Thank for this. The thing for `Make` is if the argument is `makefile` or `Makefile`, not a file extension of `.m`. How would I modify this so it recognizes the string as the file type? Ive tried putting something like `if(argv[i] == "makefile") makeCount++;` but it still seems to accept it as `other`

Comment: @RobBor Use `strcmp`  like `if(strcmp(argv[i], "makefile") == 0)` instead of `if(argv[i] == "makefile")`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Good idea. But im not having any luck :( Ive tried putting it inside the `if( len > 2 && ...`, and before it, but none seem to be working.

Comment: @RobBor I think you are doing something strange. I think that it will work.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  @H.S. is `if((strcmp(argv[i], "Makefile")==0) || (strcmp(argv[i], "makefile")==0) ){
                    makeCount++;
                    continue;
                                       
                    }` wrong?

Comment: @RobBor That is not bad.

Comment: @RobBor I think you are doing something strange. I think that it will work.

Comment: @RobBor _its not working._ is not an explanation. [mcve].

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Its counting the `makefile` as `Other` thus counting for `other`, and not counting `makefile` at all

Comment: @RobBor Although I guess, I think that the application order of conditions is bad. Please add your current code to the question (not a modify) and show the current code.Otherwise, we have no way to confirm.